# Calling C++ functions in MASM

Tags: c++, assembly, linker, masm

I'm working on a program that will use MASM to call some C++ functions. I defined, in a separate file, to sum 2 integers and display the output.

Currently, I can't get 'main.cpp' to run `asmMain()` to call functions from 'main.cpp'.

#### code.asm

```
; ---------------------------------------
    
promptFirst PROTO C
promptSecond PROTO C
printInt PROTO C

.586
.model flat, stdcall

.stack 4096

; ---------------------------------------

.DATA

first DWORD 0
second DWORD 0

; --------------------------------

.CODE

asmMain PROC C  
    mov first, promptFirst              
    ret 
asmMain ENDP

PUBLIC asmMain  
END
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void asmMain();

int promptFirst();
int promptSecond();
void printInt(int myint);
    
int main() {
    asmMain();
}

int promptFirst() {
    cout << " The first number = ";
    int newint;
    cin >> newint;

    return newint;
}

int promptSecond() {
    cout << "\nThe second number = ";
    int newint;
    cin >> newint;

    return newint;
}

void printInt(int myint) {
    cout << myint;
}
```

The error I get for the current code is such:

> Build started: Project: Project_Name, Configuration: Debug Win32
> main.cpp
> code.obj: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _promptFirst referenced in function _asmMain

Any hints on how to resolve this?

Comment: Why such a big left margin? And you might want to dump the symbols from "main.o", to see what the decorated names are.

Comment: `extern "C" int promptFirst();`, otherwise `promptFirst()` will have a mangled name.

Comment: _"However now it still doesn't seem to be calling the functions, ie. prompting the user for input."_ Where are you expecting the call to `promptFirst` to come from? All you do in the code you've shown us is `mov first, promptFirst`, which doesn't perform any function call. All that `mov` does it read the first DWORD located at the address of `promptFirst` and store it into `first`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that C++ compilers [*mangles* the symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B), which is one of the reasons behind the `extern "C"` construct, so that symbols are not mangled.

If you declare the function to be `extern "C"` then the compiler will not mangle the name, just like you do with the assembler function you call.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dumpbin.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y05bd5.aspx) on your object-file to get the mangled name of your C++ functions.

Or ask for a symbol with C-linkage using `extern "C"` on the function-declarations in your C++ code.

Then you will know what to call in your assembly-code.